# Symfony 4.3 validation doesn't work - not even the automatic

Tags: php, validation, symfony4

everyone.
There is a similar question posted here, but the answer does not solve my error.

I'm trying to use Symfony 4.3 automatic validation on an entity, but it just doesn't work.

I've uncommented the two lines from `validator.yaml` and I have enabled `validation: {enable_annotations: true}` in `framework.yaml` config file, and it still does not work.

Even if I add or remove @Assert annotations from the entity, the validation always returns a zero-length array.

This is my entity class:

```php
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Company
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="company")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CompanyRepository")
 */

class Company
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="type", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotNull
     */
    public $type;
}
```

As you can see, the type attribute cannot be null, but the validation is not working as expected. This is it:

```php
$company = new Company();
$validator = Validation::createValidator();
$errors = $validator->validate($company);
```

At this point, $errors is just an empty array.

Is there any extra configuration needed?
Does anybody have a theory?

Comment: I think you're missing the [part that reads the annotation as configuration](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/validator/resources.html#the-annotationloader).

Comment: if you're using the symfony framework though, it should work if you just let symfony auto-wire (DI) a ValidatorInterface, which is shown here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html#using-the-validator-service

Comment: @Jakumi You were right, instantiating the validator does not work. When I injected it, validations started to work. Thanks a lot for your time.